# ImageDescriptor exception in RCP Application

Tags: java, image, swt, rcp

I am a newbie to EclipseRCP and I am trying to get a product from EclipseRCP. In my program, I am loading some images(flags for language switches etc.). I am trying to load them in this way:

```
Image favcon= AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin("HelloRCP", 
                  "images/configuration.jpg").createImage(display);
```

There are also some other place that I use this code snippet (I am defining a new Image instance at that time). I got a Null pointer exception at that second usage of image descriptor. What can be reason for this situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the images in `images` in the root directory?

Try using `"/images/configuration.jpg"` instead of `"images/configuration.jpg"`